# Inline assignment statements

Tags: c++, char, buffer, assignment-operator

I am going through a implementation of a LZSS decompression algorithm where there is a buffer of 4096 chars (or whatever size you like). This implementation outputted the file to a char* where as I wanted to output a file using std::ofstream. I did get this to work but in a weird/quirky fashion (at least to me). It has something to do with the assign operator from what I can tell. All the types are the same (char)

If have

```
outputFileStream.write((char *) &buffer[byteIndex1++ & 0xFFF]);
buffer[byteIndex2++ & 0xFFF] = buffer[byteIndex1 & 0xFFF];
```

this will fail and give me corrupt data but if I have this

```
char temporary;

buffer[byteIndex2++ & 0xFFF] = temporary = buffer[byteIndex1++ & 0xFFF];

outputFileStream.write((char *) &temporary, 1);
```

that will work. Am I not understanding the order of operations that are taking place? (Execution of operations right to left) If I am then would not those two code snippets work the same?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could anyone explain these undefined behaviors (i = i++ + ++i , i = i++, etc...)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc). Read [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points), too.

Comment: So in my case the undefined behavior is (byteIndex# & 0xFFF) or the assignment themselves? So I need to play with the order to figure out what the ordering should be.

Comment: Here is the same code defined properly (I think)
    byteIndex1 &= 0xFFF;
    byteIndex2 &= 0xFFF;
    outputFileStream.write((char *) &buffer.at(byteIndex1), 1);
    buffer.at(byteIndex1) =  (buffer.at(byteIndex2));
    byteIndex1++;
    byteIndex2++;